# Using Anaconda python directory in Atom IDE

Tags: anaconda, atom-editor, path-variables, sublime-anaconda, python-install

I have installed Anaconda on my Windows 10 system. Now I want to use python in newly installed Atom IDE. Atom cannot find python directory as it's not added to the environment variable path.

I installed python 3.6 separately and added it to path variables to overcome this issue. However, I still run into issues like missing .dll files. I found that this will continue as long as there Anaconda is installed on the system.

Is there a way I can add Anaconda python path to Atom or should I just add Anaconda library to path variables (which is not recommended by Anaconda)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run python scripts inside atom, install **script** package from atom packages. Then open anaconda prompt, `cd` into your preferred directory and run `atom .` Now when you run **Ctrl+Shift+B** to run your python scripts, this script package will run with anaconda python.

Comment: Ooops!! I didn't see the question was asked 3 years ago.